# Multiple -like values in foreach statement

Tags: powershell, foreach

If I have an array with computer names, such as:

```
foows001
foows002
barws003
barws004
zzzws001
zzzws002
```

... and then I process this array with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($item in $Computers) {

        if ( $item.hostname -like $ComputersToSearch ) {
            Write-Host $item.hostname 
}
```

I want to use multiple values for `-like` and store them in an array for easy handling.

```
$ComputersToSearch = =@("foo*","bar*")
```

I've also tried a second `foreach` statement, but didn't succeed. Any advice on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match against multiple expressions.

1. Declare array of computer names
2. Declare multiple regular expression conditions (note the `-join` on the pipe character `|`)
3. Match each computer name

Code:

```
# Declare array of computer names
$ComputerList = @(
      'foows001'
    , 'foows002'
    , 'barws003'
    , 'barws004'
    , 'zzzws001'
    , 'zzzws002'
    );

# Declare array of regular expression matches
$SearchList = @('^foo', '^bar') -join '|';

# Iterate of list of computers, and match against regular expression
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    if ($Computer -match $SearchList) {
        Write-Host -Object "$Computer matched search criteria";
    }
}
```

### Results

```
foows001 matched search criteria
foows002 matched search criteria
barws003 matched search criteria
barws004 matched search criteria
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Can you point me to a resource that contains an explanation for the $Searchlist line ? Also, am i allowed to extend the question ?

Comment: You can open up a new question if you have specific questions about building regular expressions. There aren't really any limits to how many questions you can ask, but I think they try to keep them limited to a single, main question per-post. Anyway, the `$SearchList` line is basically an array of regular expression matches that are joined together by the pipe character. Do some more reading on regex in general, and I think you'll find what you need!